# why isn't my validator working?

Tags: jquery, validation

can anybody tell me why is the following code not working?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        // validate contact form on keyup and submit
        $("#myform").validate({
            //set the rules for the fild names
            rules: {
                hour: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 2,
                    range:[0,23]
                },
                minute: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 2,
                    range:[0,60]
                },
            },
            //set messages to appear inline
            messages: {
                hour: "Please enter a valid hour",
                minute: "Please enter a valid minute"
            }
        });

    });
</script>
 <style type="text/css">
.error {
    color: red;
    font: 12pt verdana;
    padding-left: 10px
}
</style>

   <form id="myform" method="" action="">

   <input id="hour" type="text" name="hour" style="width:30px; text-align:center;"></input> :

    <input id="minute" type="text" name="minute" style="width:30px; text-align:center;"></input>
  <br/>
  <input type="submit" value="Validate!" />
</form>
```

thanks a million in advance,
Lina

Comment: Yes, can anyone reading this question read minds? give us a clue, what errors are you getting in Firebug etc.

Comment: Sorry for not specifying clearly, i'm a beginner :)
i'm not getting any errors or warnings nor anything else, it's just not working!, i'm not getting any error message when entering wrong values, and when clicking the button "Validate" then all what i had wrote in the fields just disappear, why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see anything wrong with your code. Make sure that the address of the included scripts is correct. Here's a working example using jquery and jquery.validate from Microsoft CDN:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>test</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    .error {
        color: red;
        font: 12pt verdana;
        padding-left: 10px
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
   <form id="myform" action="">
       <input id="hour" type="text" name="hour" style="width:30px; text-align:center;" /> :
       <input id="minute" type="text" name="minute" style="width:30px; text-align:center;" />
       <br/>
       <input type="submit" value="Validate!" />
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.5.5/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        // validate contact form on keyup and submit
        $("#myform").validate({
            //set the rules for the fild names
            rules: {
                hour: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 2,
                    range:[0,23]
                },
                minute: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 2,
                    range:[0,60]
                },
            },
            //set messages to appear inline
            messages: {
                hour: "Please enter a valid hour",
                minute: "Please enter a valid minute"
            }
        });

    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Agreed, I tried it myself (using other links for the js-files) and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Simple Form Validation</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jquery.com/view/trunk/plugins/validate/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#myform").validate({
        //set the rules for the fild names
        rules: {
            hour: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 2,
                range:[0,23]
            },
            minute: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 2,
                range:[0,60]
            },
        },
        //set messages to appear inline
        messages: {
            hour: "Please enter a valid hour",
            minute: "Please enter a valid minute"
        }
    });
});
</script>

<style type="text/css">
.error {
    color: red;
    font: 12pt verdana;
    padding-left: 10px
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="myform" method="" action="">
        <input id="hour" type="text" name="hour" style="width:30px; text-align:center;"></input>
        <input id="minute" type="text" name="minute" style="width:30px; text-align:center;"></input>
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Validate!" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

is working